# Treeview And Panel in C#, Case go to next form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a desktop application using treeview and Panel it works fine a bit. But when i try to does not change like for instance, if i click Account opening, it opens the form, but if i click to go to a different form inside the application (For instance Transfers) it doesn't change , you have to restart the form again to move to another form inside the main application My source code looks like this :

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Node.Text)
    {
        case "Account Opening":
            f = new AccountOpening();
            f.TopLevel = false;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(f);
            f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            f.Show();
            break;

        case "Check Balance":
            f = new CheckBalance();
            f.TopLevel = false;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(f);
            f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            f.Show();
            break;

        case "Deposit":
            f = new Deposit();
            f.TopLevel = false;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(f);
            f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            f.Show();
            break;

        case "Loan Repayment":
            f = new LoanRepayment();
            f.TopLevel = false;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(f);
            f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            f.Show();
            break;


        case "Transfers":
            f = new Transfers();
            f.TopLevel = false;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(f);
            f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            f.Show();
            break;

        case "Withdrawal":
            f = new Withdrawal();
            f.TopLevel = false;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(f);
            f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            f.Show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Apparently what am i missing?

Full code Looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace xConsoleP
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            this.treeView1.Nodes[0].ExpandAll();
        }

        private Form f;
        private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode node = treeView1.SelectedNode; 
            switch (node.Text)
            {
                case "Account Opening":
                    //f.Dispose();
                    f = new AccountOpening();
                    f.TopLevel = false;
                    this.panel1.Controls.Add(f);
                    f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    f.Show();
                    break;

                case "Check Balance":
                    //f.Dispose();
                    f = new CheckBalance();
                    f.TopLevel = false;
                    this.panel1.Controls.Add(f);
                    f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    f.Show();
                    break;

                case "Deposit":
                   // f.Dispose();
                    f = new Deposit();
                    f.TopLevel = false;
                    this.panel1.Controls.Add(f);
                    f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    f.Show();
                    break;

                case "Loan Repayment":
                    //f.Dispose();
                    f = new LoanRepayment();
                    f.TopLevel = false;
                    this.panel1.Controls.Add(f);
                    f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    f.Show();
                    break;


                case "Transfers":
                   // f.Dispose();
                    f = new Transfers();
                    f.TopLevel = false;
                    this.panel1.Controls.Add(f);
                    f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    f.Show();
                    break;

                case "Withdrawal":
                    //f.Dispose();
                    f = new Withdrawal();
                    f.TopLevel = false;
                    this.panel1.Controls.Add(f);
                    f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    f.Show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want(wanted) a TreeView and a Panel on either side.  When you click on a TreeView Node you update the Panel UserControl according to the node?